# "Use of undeclared identifier A"

Tags: c++

Any ideas on what is causing this compile-time error?

Basic setup:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "GroupTheorizer.h"

int main()
{
    // ... 
        functs::Adder<char> A; // error on this line
    / ...

    return 0;
}
```

**GroupTheorizer.h**

```
#ifndef __GroupTheory__GroupTheorizer__
#define __GroupTheory__GroupTheorizer__

class GroupTheorizer
{
   // definitions of members of a GroupTheorizer object
   // ...
};

#endif /* defined(__GroupTheory__GroupTheorizer__) */
```

**GroupTheorizer.cpp**

```
#include "GroupTheorizer.h"

#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>


// ... implementations of GroupTheorizer members
// ... 

namespace functs
{

class Adder
{
private:
    static const char symbol = '+';
public:
    T operator() (const T & x, const T & y) const { return x + y; };
    char getSymbol(void) const { return symbol; };
};

// other functors ...
// ...
}
```

I'm fairly certain I linked the files together correctly, so what could be the problem?

Comment: `Adder` appears to be a templated class but your example doesn't show this as such.

Comment: Rather, `Adder` is *not* a template class, but the line with the error uses it as if it was.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour due to `__GroupTheory__GroupTheorizer__` - names containing two or more adjacent underscores are reserved (as are names starting with a single underscore followed by an uppercase letter, and in global scope, names starting with a single underscore).

Comment: @owlstead It's not the cause of the OP's problem, merely a separate issue with the code.

Comment: @JBentley Ok, sorry about that, just reviewing questions, it looked like an answer to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your implementation of `Adder`, it seems like you mean it to be a template but haven't written it as such.

You're only missing the `template <typename T>` line.

```
template <typename T>
class Adder
{
private:
    static const char symbol = '+';
public:
    T operator() (const T & x, const T & y) const { return x + y; };
    char getSymbol(void) const { return symbol; };
};
```

Comment: I think this might not be the problem (but I could well be wrong): if this is the problem, the OP should be getting errors about the `T operator() (...)` member well before the error the OP is asking about.